# Can i see allure index.html report file in teamcity report tab for each build?

Tags: teamcity, allure

I am trying to see is there any option to open allure report inside teamcity once build execution is over.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. Go to "Edit project" in teamcity, find on the left "Report Tabs" and there you can add the name of tab and path to the file.

[image]